# Portable Executable File Without Any Dependencies Nor Import

Tags: c++, c, visual-c++, portable-executable

I have a program installed on my computer. And when I checked it with CFF Explorer, I couldn't see any imports or dependencies. It was probably written in Delphi. So how can this type of PE work? The authors of the program seem to want to hide which system DLLs were used. Can I build such PE files in my own Visual Studio C / C ++ environment?

This is what the PE file looks like in CFF EXplorer:

[image]

[image]

Edit: That is the screenshot of PE Explorer. PE Explorer also says there is no dependency.

[image]

Comment: I'd guess either CFF Explorer is wrong, and something in the file format has confused it so it's reporting no imports, or they've done something like copied the implementations of LoadLibraryEx and GetProcAddress from User32 i.e. they're making the interrupt calls themselves, and then used those to import more functions as needed. I've no idea how compatible this is across Windows versions and updates - this is a private API after all - or why you'd actually want to do this.

Comment: I think the second option is more likely. In fact, we want to hide which DLLs and functions our application uses. But this seems to be quite arduous.

Comment: Could you please provide the executable you analysed? I would like to test deeper in the structure of the executable. Thank you in advance1

Comment: One of the reason for this emptyness of the import table is, that the executable file contains ONLY Resources! This is really common.

Comment: @mox Since the software I am analyzing is a commercial product, it may not be appropriate to disclose the product. But if you can contact me at the following address, I can tell you the name of the software: l5216006@std.yildiz.edu.tr.

Comment: @mox Hello, no, the executable has a .text section and it is a standart desktop app that has a GUI.

Answer (score 2):

It is quite easy to generate an executable with no imports. Since this is about Windows I'll give an example using MSVC.

All you need to do is go to the *project Properties* -> *Linker* -> *Input* and set `Ignore All Default Libraries` to `Yes /NODEFAULTLIB`.

You will need to provide your own version of `mainCRTstartup` which is the default name for the entry point set by MSVC. You can change this by going to *project Properties* -> *Linker* -> *Advanced* and set `Entry Point` to the name of the function you want to use as an entry point.

Or, using directly `cl.exe` from the command line: `cl.exe main.c /link /NODEFAULTLIB /ENTRY:"main"`. Full example:

```
$ more main.c
int main()
{
    return 0;
}

$ cl.exe main.c /link /NODEFAULTLIB /ENTRY:"main"
Microsoft (R) C/C++ Optimizing Compiler Version 19.28.29333 for x86
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

main.c
Microsoft (R) Incremental Linker Version 14.28.29333.0
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

/out:main.exe
/NODEFAULTLIB
/ENTRY:main
main.obj

$ dumpbin /imports main.exe
Microsoft (R) COFF/PE Dumper Version 14.28.29333.0
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.


Dump of file main.exe

File Type: EXECUTABLE IMAGE

  Summary

        1000 .rdata
        1000 .text
```

Of course, this means that you can not use any of the Win32 APIs. Even if you statically link a C runtime library provided by MSVC it would still not work, as it will use functionality from the system DLLs. You can workaround this if you invoke the syscalls you need directly (as long as you know their number, which may change from one Windows version to another).

Comment: In fact, I was not asking how to create an executable without imports. I was asking how the executable could work and call the subsystem dlls. With the help of @mox, I was able to call the subsystem functions using TEB structure.